# 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-6

I am having an issue where I've got an asp.net mvc4 application being published via web deploy to our staging server.  The behavior I am seeing is that, when accessed from the Staging server itself, the app operates just fine, but when accessed by a remote device, I get the error `401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.`

Where things get really weird for me is if I open IIS on the staging server: `-> select the site -> click on error pages -> edit feature settings -> select Detailed errors`  Once "Detailed Errors is selected, even the remote browser begins to work just fine.  But as soon as I toggle the errors back to some flavor of "custom", then the remote browser fails again.

To add insult to injury, nothing is being caught by my ELMAH, nor by the staging server event logs, nor by the IIS logs.

How can I resolve this error when turning on the "Detailed Errors" seems to somehow resolve the issue.  Obviously, the answer is not to just leave "Detailed Errors" on....

Thanks.

#### UPDATE #1

Based on the answer referenced by @sarhdan, I discovered that I had in a shared Layout a call to an action on a controller that had recently been placed in a controller wide `[Authorize]`.  So, whenever I was forced to head to my login page, which consumed that layout, it got into a bit of a circular dependency...it can't render the login page, because I'm not logged in, so I can't access a resource needed to render the login page......

## Bonus Question For which I will offer extra points :D:

Why does the "Detailed errors" setting cause this error to "magically" resolve...the actual issue is still there, and SHOULD still be generating an error...... ?

Comment: The question at: http://serverfault.com/questions/137073/401-unauthorized-on-server-2008-r2-iis-7-5 seems to be the same issue.

Comment: indeed, thanks!  Can you add that as an answer, and I'll give you the credit?

Comment: @Will ,  can you explain why this topic was closed?  I don't feel the topic is off topic at all.  It is most definitely related to programming and software development...  The fix, answered by user sarhdan illuminated a bug in my programming...  I just don't understand how this isn't relevant; could you explain ?

Comment: It was my impression (and that of the flaggers) that since the answer was on serverfault, and this question appears to deal with IIS rather than asp.net mvc, that it was an administrative problem rather than a coding problem.  I understand that the referenced answer pointed not to an administration issue but to an issue in your controllers, so I've reopened.  Unfortunately, we don't allow answers that are nothing more than links to other questions.  If @sarhdan would [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15010289/edit) his answers to explain the solution he can flag and have it undeleted.

Comment: ...that makes sense.  Thanks for explaining.  And for re-opening!

Comment: @reidLinden I have hot the same issue, did you find out why setting `Detailed errors` seem to fix the issue?